# Stop code execution while debugging in Eclipse without terminating the thread

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Is there a way how to stop debugging when program hits the breakpoint (i.e. I don't want to execute the code after it) without stopping entire application server (I am programming apps in Java, server is JBoss)?

I know only one way how to stop debug - red button with title Terminate which shuts down the server. So is there anything else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can hit the disconnect button. See the attached image. This will continue execution and stopping debugging without stopping the server.
[image]

Comment: op says he doesn't want the subsequent code to be executed. Why is this answer accepted?

Answer (score 8):

While debugging, [context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdKY1.png) offers you to force a return. This instantly leaves the method and will take you back to the caller. One can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks neun24, yours' the correct answer.
Unfortunately I'm getting a nasty "Error evaluating: -1" error when trying to force return via Alt+Shift+F on Eclipse 2019.03 while debugging Appengine locally (which relies on Jetty).

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "I do not want the code after my breakpoint to execute", then you could use a [conditional breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7194326/edit) to execute a `return` from that method.

(Note that you can execute any code you like in a conditional breakpoint. It does not have to be just a condition.)